# Selenium Maximize Window in a Suite

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

Hey guys Im trying to use driver.manage().window().maximize(); within each class that is enclose within a suite.

I would create the driver then maximize it. However when adding these classes that use these After and Before calls into a suite they do not run together. The first test will always run but the second will never open the driver after it closes. However, if I do remove the .maxamize() call they all work together and in isolation.

```
driver = new SafariDrive();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("localhost:3000");
```

then in AfterClass:

```
driver.quit();
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @mrogers sorrey forgot to add the question. When include driver.manage().window().maximize() in a collection of classes that is defined within a Suite it does not open the other classes and complains about the driver already listening on a port. It shouldnt do this because I call driver.quit() in AfterClass of my classes.

Comment: Anyone? I feel like this is a bug. The test work independently but when adding them to a sutie and running it, it will stop after the first test and fail to open the driver again..